# Remove file from input field

Tags: php, javascript

I am working on file uploading. So when I click cross button how can I remove exited file using php without page reload?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, with javascript

```
document.getElementById("fileInput").value = "";
```

> How can I remove exited file using php without page reload?

You can't, PHP is server side language

Comment: *"how can I remove [...] file using php"*

Comment: @LinusKleen: Added an answer to this piece of question ;)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery version

`$("#id").attr('value', '');` or  `$("#id").val('');`

Also check out this article: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data

Comment: Really? jQuery for such a task?

Answer (score -1):

if you're using jQuery:

```
$("#remove").click(function(){
   $("#fileInput").val("");
   return false;
})
```